# Iterating through feature classes in geodatabase using ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I’m trying to create a model so I can iterate through some feature classes in my gdb. I remember doing it one time while working on wetlands with the US states, where I used the state boundary shape file and the select by attributes tool.

How do I connect the Select by attributes tool to the Iterate Model to enable me select the feature classes I want to use a geoprocessing tool on?

I created a shapefile (utilities) with the list of selections with the names matching the feature classes in the gdb.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect the output "anomaly" to a make feature layer tool that becomes the input to the select layer by attribute tool. You need to do this because that tool takes as input a feature layer the output of the iterator is a feature class which is a very different type of object.